# How to set custom attributes to user details object in spring security 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

The question says it all. In spring security 2.x we can set the custom values to the user in the userattributes. Is there a similar/alternate way of doing the same in spring secuirty 3.0??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117944/ldapuserdetails-mapper-changed-in-spring-security-3-0) earlier and nobody answered it. After some research I found that they don't have a way of doing it directly. Only way is to override the spring specific classes and do it.

Comment: @TejaKantamneni can you point me where can I find a sample code for doing that?

Comment: @Madhavi http://www.jeviathon.com/2009/09/spring-30-mapping-active-directory-ldap.html